# Can't convert decimal numbers with Str function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, function

I want to build a new column that combines two other columns, one is numeric and the other one is `nvarchar`. I have tried the code below but it got rid of the numbers after comma.

```
select ltrim(str([Number])) + ' ' + Units as [Unique] from [Table1]
```

I want an output like this   "0.00 m2". How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CAST` in T-SQL:

```
select 
    ltrim(CAST([Number] AS VARCHAR(20))) + ' ' + Units AS [Unique] 
from 
    [Table1]
```

Comment: In fact, TSQL does have `str` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you need two digits after comma when using [str function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) - you have to specify it explicitly.

This function syntax is:

```
STR (float_expression [ , length [ ,decimal ] ] )
```

Here `length` is the total length of output string and `decimal` is the number of places to the right of the decimal point.

So in your case it should be something like

```
ltrim(str([Number], 10, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no str function in ms sql. You have to use convert function

```
select ltrim(convert(nvarchar,Number)) + ' ' + Units as [Unique] from Table1
```

Comment: Thank for answer it worked well. It is outputing like this  24.640000 m3 How i can limite this column to 24,64 m3.